# How to simulate a stereo recording?

Tags: audio

I have a single channel audio recording. I want to simulate the stereo recording when it is (hypothetically) played on a speaker in front of stereo mics (distance between them - say 10 cm).

Are there any tools which can do this?

Edit- I am looking for something more precise - as in for specific distance between speaker and mics and also for given room dimensions. I tried Audacity 'Reverb tool' which sort of does stereofication but there is no way to specify certain distances (speaker-mic, mic-mic etc.)

Comment: If my answer is not the answer you want... Edit your question for better answers otherwise can you accept my answer?

Comment: @Jan-Bert thanks for answer but I did not find what I was looking for. I was looking for something more precise - as in for specific distance between speaker and mics and also for given room dimensions. I tried Audacity 'Reverb tool' which sort of does stereofication but there is no way to specify certain distances (speaker-mic, mic-mic etc.)

Comment: I think the reason for that is the way of working of sound engineers etc. A sound engineer want a result not a method or physically correct model.

Let explain me with a sample measurement:
**What is your environment?** Free Field_(No reflections)_; Near Field_(close distance particles not in phase)_; far field_(6dB damping double distance)_, direct field_(just sound from source)_ and reverberant  field_(reflections of your room)_
**What is the shape of the room?** square; round; dome; horse shoe; etc
**What is the size of the room?** (see environment)

Comment: **What materials are used in the room?** wood; stone. are the materials soft; hard; flat or course?
**Is the room filled with** products/ materials/ shapes etc.
**Where is the mic placed?**
This means a lot of options.

In sound engineering they try to fix this amount of parameters to replace with less.
The parameters they use are: size; shape; early reflection (distance mic from speaker) ; decay/reverb time; damping; filter options; mix(direct sound vs reverb); etc

Answer (score 1):

Check a music production software (commercial: Logic/ Ableton/ Pro Tools. Open Source: Ardour, Mu Lab) or otherwise audacity. Add a stereo widening tool plugin.
For that check KVR Audio
[stereo/ imaging/ widening](http://www.kvraudio.com/q.php?search=1&q=&tg[]=64&pr[]=f)
[stereo imaging](http://www.kvraudio.com/q.php?search=1&q=&tg[]=2586&pr[]=f) more close search